# Create text with cutout through letter leaving cutout part transparent

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, pathfinder

I need to create a logo. It's very basic but I cannot figure out how to achieve my desisred effect with Adobe Illustrator.

Like the image before, I need to have a part of the text cut out. I tried using a white rectangle and under pathfinder I used divide but that leaves me with the white rectangle attached still.

I need the part that is cut out to be transparent.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Set the Text
- `Type > Create Outlines`
- Draw the rectangle
- Grab the **Shape Builder Tool**
- Hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and click-drag across rectangle

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the rectangle is behind the type (that has been converted to outlines). Then try the Pathfinder tool: Minus Back.